# passing a number with leading zeroes to function

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that has an argument like below:

```
myfunction<-function(id){
print(paste(id, ".", "csv", sep=""))
}
```

when the id value is like this 009, it prints it as 9.csv not 009.csv.

I tried this:

```
id<-as.character(id)
```

this is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use e.g. `sprintf()`:

```
myfunction <- function(id) {
    sprintf("%03d.csv", id)
}
```

which gives

```
R> cat(myfunction(9), "\n")
009.csv 
R> cat(myfunction(199), "\n")
199.csv 
R>
```

Answer (score 4):

Although you already accepted @Dirk's answer...

The problem is you are passing your input as a numeric. For R, `009` evaluates to `9`:

```
> 009
[1] 9
```

so when you run `myfunction(009)`, it really runs `myfunction(9)`. It should be no surprise you get "9.csv" as your output.

Instead, you should pass your input as a character: "009":

```
> myfunction("009")
[1] "009.csv"
```

Comment: While this works in this example, the problem is that you won't always be able to type in the parameters from a command line and add the "", sometimes the function will be called from another function that you have no control over and that does not add "", simply 009 and you have to make sure it doesn't become 9 in your function. That is the answer that I am searching for (and brought me here)